# registerUserNotificationSettings is not firing delegates and push notification not working my project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification

I did all the procedures written in the documentation. That is my code. When I added breakpoint, this delegates was not called.

```
private func pushNotificationHandler(_ application: UIApplication){
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // program never come here
    print(deviceToken)
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    // program never come here
    print(error)
}
```

edit: tested in iphone 6 is working done, but iPhone 11 pro max , iPhone XS Max And iPhone 7 are the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add

```
FirebaseApp.configure() 
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

in **Appdelegate->didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

Comment: pushNotificationHandler function already added top of the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.

Comment: Did you add Push Notifications in Target- > Signing&Capablities

Comment: Yes. Everything is ok, I tested in 4 device. 1 device is working, 3 device is the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The internet connection of the phone cannot connect with apple push servers. After 10 hours, I changed the DNS and solved the problem.